# Issue with parsing json

Tags: apex, json, parsing

//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

```
public class Status {
    public String self;
    public String description;
    public String iconUrl;
    public String name;
    public String id;
    public StatusCategory statusCategory;
}

public class Project {
    public String self;
    public String id;
    public String key;
    public String name;
    public String projectTypeKey;
    public Boolean simplified;
    public AvatarUrls avatarUrls;
    public ProjectCategory projectCategory;
}

public class StatusCategory {
    public String self;
    public Integer id;
    public String key;
    public String colorName;
    public String name;
}

public class Fields {
    public Issuetype issuetype;
    public Creator creator;
    public Project project;
    public Reporter reporter;
    public Assignee assignee;
    public List<String> customfield_10010;
    public List<FixVersions> fixVersions;
    public Priority priority;
    public Status status;
}

public String expand;
public Integer startAt;
public Integer maxResults;
public Integer total;
public List<Issues> issues;


public class ProjectCategory {
    public String self;
    public String id;
    public String description;
    public String name;
}

public class FixVersions {
    public String version;
}

public class Priority {
    public String self;
    public String iconUrl;
    public String name;
    public String id;
}

public class Issues {
    public String expand;
    public String id;
    public String self;
    public String key;
    public Fields fields;
}

public class Issuetype {
    public String self;
    public String id;
    public String description;
    public String iconUrl;
    public String name;
    public Boolean subtask;
}

public class AvatarUrls {

}

public Class Reporter{
    public String self;
    public String accountId;
    public Map<String,String> avatarUrls;
    public String displayName;
    public Boolean active;
    public String timeZone;
    public String accountType;
}

public Class Assignee{
    public String self;
    public String accountId;
    public Map<String,String> avatarUrls;
    public String displayName;
    public Boolean active;
    public String timeZone;
    public String accountType;
}

public class Creator {
    public String self;
    public String accountId;
    public Map<String,String> avatarUrls;
    public String displayName;
    public Boolean active;
    public String timeZone;
    public String accountType;
}


public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
    Json2apex jsonInfo =(JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    System.debug(jsonInfo);
    for(Json2Apex.issues IssueInfo: jsonInfo.issues){

        Json2Apex.Fields IssueFields = new  Json2Apex.Fields();
                    if(IssueInfo.fields != null){
                        IssueFields = IssueInfo.fields;//IssueFields
                    }
        System.debug(IssueFields.customfield_10010);
    }
    return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
}
```

}

**This is the json i am using and the List customfield_10010 is becoming null**.

{
    "expand": "names,schema",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 1,
    "total": 476,
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "fields": {
                "issuetype": {
                    "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "id": "10003",
                    "description": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "iconUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": "Story",
                    "subtask": false
                },
                "creator": {
                    "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "24x24": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "16x16": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "32x32": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "displayName": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
                    "accountType": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                "customfield_10053": 0,
                "project": {
                    "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "id": "10012",
                    "key": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": "xxxxx",
                    "projectTypeKey": "software",
                    "simplified": false,
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "24x24": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "16x16": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "32x32": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "projectCategory": {
                        "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "id": "10000",
                        "description": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                },
                "customfield_10010": [
                    "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@xxxxxx[id=81,rapidViewId=15,state=CLOSED,name=xxxxxx,goal=,startDate=2018-05-01T14:10:33.507Z,endDate=2018-05-31T15:10:00.000Z,completeDate=2018-07-23T17:58:31.853Z,sequence=81]"
                ],
                "reporter": {
                    "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "24x24": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "16x16": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "32x32": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "displayName": "xxxxxxx",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
                    "accountType": "atlassian"
                },
                "fixVersions": [],
                "assignee": {
                    "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "24x24": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "16x16": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "32x32": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                    "displayName": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "active": false,
                    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
                    "accountType": "xxxxxx"
                },
                "priority": {
                    "self": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "iconUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": "Low",
                    "id": "4"
                },
                "status": {
                    "self": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": "To Do",
                    "id": "10000",
                    "statusCategory": {
                        "self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "id": 2,
                        "key": "new",
                        "colorName": "blue-gray",
                        "name": "To Do"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Your classes don't match your JSON.

```
public List<customfield_10010> customfield_10010;


public Class customfield_10010{

}
```

versus

```
"customfield_10010": [
    "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@xxxxxx[id=81,rapidViewId=15,state=CLOSED,name=xxxxxx,goal=,startDate=2018-05-01T14:10:33.507Z,endDate=2018-05-31T15:10:00.000Z,completeDate=2018-07-23T17:58:31.853Z,sequence=81]"
],
```

The value of that field appears to be a `List<String>`, not a `List` of a class with no members.

Comment: @David.Thank you for the reply. i tried by making it a list<String> also but still its giving null.

Comment: i have reedited and posted the code .please check and can you know what is wrong in that code

Answer (score -1):

Actually  the way i am calling out to jira using a field name is wrong,The field name should be customfield_10010 but i am using CustomField_10010(caps). which is not sending any data for this.

Thank you .